# Contents of table view cells change after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a xib and created a UITableViewController. In my cellForRowAtIndex, I dequeue and set a custom table cell like this:

```
 CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.delegate = self;
```

then I set some conditions just to set up the cells. I did something like this:

```
 if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5) {
    cell.addressLabel.hidden = YES;
 } else {
     cell.storeHourTitle.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
     cell.addressLabel.hidden = NO;
 }
```

just to show more information, my heightForRowAtIndexPath has:

```
  if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 5) {
        return 280;
  } else {
        return 520;
  }
```

I've also set:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.datasource = self
```

but I don't think it's necessary? since I'm using a UITableViewController, please verify this for me.

So now when I run my app, the cells load properly, at least the first 5. Once I scroll down, the 5th row's content is incorrect and when I scroll back up, some of the contents change. (e.g. the first cell's content becomes the last cell's (row = 6))

I only return 6 in my numberOfRowsInSection.

Am I not dequeueing the cell properly? From what I've learned, if I use

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier forIndexPath
```

I don't have to do a

```
if (cell == nil)
```

because it will always return something. If you guys spotted any flaw in my UITableView logic, please point it out to me, Thanks!

EDIT:

More detailed code cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
CustomStoreTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomStoreTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.delegate = self;
if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 6) {

    cell.operatingHoursLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.operatingHoursLabel2.hidden = YES;
    cell.addressLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.numberLabel.hidden = YES;

    cell.storeHourTitle.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.storeHourTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.addressTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.phoneTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.emailTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.emailLabel.hidden = YES;

}
else{

    cell.topImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Picture"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.operatingHoursLabel.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.operatingHoursLabel2.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

    cell.addressLabel.text = [[self.dict objectForKey:@"Address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    cell.addressLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.numberLabel.text = [[self.dict objectForKey:@"Phone"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: post ur `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, if you are using `UITableViewController` you don't need to set data source and delegate. But if you do, nothing bad happens ;)

If you are seeing weird things after scrolling tableView, there is absolutely something wrong with your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. In most cases you are setting something conditionally and forgot to set or reset cell for `else` condition. Or, do you have a custom cell (A cell defined in xib) or have implemented a custom cell controller? In that case use `prepareForReuse` method to do cleanup work. (I'm guessing you are, because you are setting delegate for cells, meaning there is something going on in your cell)

But for the flaws you have been asking for, I just hope you have defined the `delegate` property of your cell as `weak` otherwise you'll get memory leaks.

After posting your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is clear for me now, you are setting some values in your `if` statement, but forgot to setting them to other values in your `else` statement. you should always set values symmetrically for your dequeued cells, otherwise they keep their old values set haphazardly in past!

it could be something like this:

```
CustomStoreTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomStoreTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.delegate = self;
if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 6) {

    cell.operatingHoursLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.operatingHoursLabel2.hidden = YES;
    cell.addressLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.numberLabel.hidden = YES;

    cell.storeHourTitle.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.storeHourTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.addressTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.phoneTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.emailTitle.hidden = YES;
    cell.emailLabel.hidden = YES;

}
else{
cell.operatingHoursLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.operatingHoursLabel2.hidden = NO;
    cell.addressLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.numberLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.addressTitle.hidden = NO;
    cell.phoneTitle.hidden = NO;
    cell.emailTitle.hidden = NO;
    cell.emailLabel.hidden = NO;
    cell.topImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Picture"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    cell.operatingHoursLabel.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.operatingHoursLabel2.text = [[[self.dict objectForKey:@"Hours"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1];

    cell.addressLabel.text = [[self.dict objectForKey:@"Address"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
    cell.addressLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.numberLabel.text = [[self.dict objectForKey:@"Phone"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
return cell;
```

Comment: I had retain for the delegate property but have changed it to weak. Thanks.

Comment: just to double check, setting retain/weak for the delegate property does not directly affect my issue of displaying the correct data right?

Comment: Of course not. If you are setting up cell in your cell's controller, please check there,. I always set my model as a property for cell, and upon set method, do the setup of my cell, therefore I have minimal code in my table view, this helps keeping table controller clean, plus it gives the benefit of reusing cell in other table controllers too. That's where most issues arise, because cell keeps track of objects inside itself and when dequeued does minimal work to reset it's values. So, I usually have a very carefully written `prepareForReuse` override to make sure nothing gets past my dequeue.

Comment: Thanks, I was totally blindsided and forgot to setting the cells symmetrically!

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem. If I may have a word of advice with you is that: don't do such a massive formatting on single cell type. It might benefit you if you had two different cell types and assign proper cells according to the indexpath instead of hide/unhiding of a single prototype.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85175/discussion-between-eric-chuang-and-m-porooshani).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is like this

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
 cell.delegate = self;
```

Change this code to like this

```
CustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomTableViewCell"];
```

You set delegate for table not cell.

Comment: Why do you think the OP's code here is wrong? Cell's can have delegates too. And why drop the `forIndexPath:` part of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`? And finally, how does this actually fix the problem asked in the question?

Comment: I have a method that I had to set delegate for the cell. I've tried using both dequeue methods, the results are still the same.